# mysql error 1069 Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed

Tags: mysql, indexing

i am trying to run alter table command and i am getting the following error:

> #1069 - Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Reduce the number of keys in the table? Seems rather self-explanator.

Comment: A bit more info like the alter table statement would be nice...

Answer (score 8):

According to the [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,53666,262189#msg-262189) you must compile with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-charset=cp1251 --enable-thread-safe-client --with-max-indexes=256
```

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a way to change after compiling.

Comment: Hi what could be the possible implications if we increase the ma-indexes count to 80 for a database table ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249472/implication-in-increasing-mysql-maximum-keys-allowed-per-table

Answer (score 0):

This error means there are more than 64 indexes on your table. Each table can only have up to 64 indexes.

You don't usually specify up to 65 indexes, so this error is caused when you run an multiple alter command in mysql and having a `UNIQUE` index on a column at all times. Because apperently, it seams alter commands is not resetting the index on a unique field but is creating a whole new index.

ie: If column ***email*** is marked `UNIQUE` an idex `email` is created for it. If you alter the table and still have `UNIQUE` on column ***email***, a new `email` index is created for the column but named as `email_2` instead of `email` which could have replaced the previouse one.

The more alter commands you write with ***email*** having `UNIQUE` would cause more `email_(n)` indexes. That is why the maximum reaches.

To prevent this error

- if your ***email*** column still have `UNIQUE` on it, remove it or first drop the previous index on the table before you run your alter command. usually ORM users, ORMs run same complete commands on every startup.
- If you have run a `UNIQUE` command, an index has already been created so don't run another one. For ORM users, remove the unique constraint from the column properties

***NOTE:*** I have only noticed this in MYSQL and I have noticed that it does not happen to other indexes like `primary`, `fulltext` etc. except `unique`.

This is something I have noticed. I hope it helps

Comment: That’s one explanation. Not necessarily the one that applies.

Answer (score -5):

Seems like the message is clear... YOu can't have a table with more than 64 keys (Primary, Foreign or even index)

Comment: how can i resolve this issue if i have a table contains more than 64 keys i.e. is there any parameter to change in order to increase this number

Comment: If this wanted to be considered an answer, than I suggest explaining why not?

Comment: @IgorL. What does it matter why not? It’s a limit. Everything has limits.