# Error too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed

Tags: mysql

I got the follow MySQL error:

```
Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed.
```

Is it possible to increase the max indexes size in MySQL, and if yes, then how we can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql error 1069 Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021586/mysql-error-1069-too-many-keys-specified-max-64-keys-allowed)

Answer (score 2):

Given the replies here: [mysql error 1069 Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021586/mysql-error-1069-too-many-keys-specified-max-64-keys-allowed)
and here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,53666,53666 (old thread from 2005, but still relevant), it seems that recompiling and publishing seems to be your only option.

This of course is difficult in case your hosting won't allow you to manually deploy a mySql installation.

Comment: This already answers your question (+1 for that) but I would like to add that having a table with 64+ keys most likely isn't normalised as it should be. In extremis, you can horizontally partition your table into two tables and have 64 keys on each one but I'd rather solve the normalisation issue.

Comment: Hi what could be the possible implications if we increase the max -indexes count to 80 or 100 for a database table ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249472/implication-in-increasing-mysql-maximum-keys-allowed-per-table

Answer (score 2):

Option 1)increase the `MAX_KEY value in 'sql/unireg.h'` and recompilet the code

or

Option 2) you can specify this at configure stage, i.e.:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-charset=cp1251 --enable-thread-safe-client --with-max-indexes=256
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021586/mysql-error-1069-too-many-keys-specified-max-64-keys-allowed) out

Comment: Hi what could be the possible implications if we increase the max-indexes count to 80 or 100 for a database table ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249472/implication-in-increasing-mysql-maximum-keys-allowed-per-table

Comment: Hi I want to use method two however I dont know where to execut it. Can you tell me how to run it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: "The maximum number of indexes per MyISAM table is 64. This can be changed by recompiling. Beginning with MySQL 5.0.18, you can configure the build by invoking configure with the --with-max-indexes=N option, where N is the maximum number of indexes to permit per MyISAM table. N must be less than or equal to 128. Before MySQL 5.0.18, you must change the source."

So, we're assuming that you're using MyISAM. If you use InnoDB, you could get as many keys as you like, as long as the data length is within the 3072 byte limit.

Why do you have so many keys? Can you redesign to use fewer?

Comment: @D Mac thank you, we are one of the big companies platforms providers, some of our DB schemas are generating on the fly. so some of our customers have faced this issue, they have in some tables more than 70 columns that require to be indexed.

Comment: Then it is probably worth the effort to reconfigure your MySQL using with-max-indexes.

Comment: yea we have finally decided that the best option is to reconfigure our MySQL and adding new validation before deploying any column that required to be indexed. and here i want to thank you again.

Comment: there is need for more keys easily, when you have to optimize `ORDER BY`

Comment: I don't think this is accurate: "If you use InnoDB, you could get as many keys as you like, as long as the data length is within the 3072 byte limit." Because from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html: "A table can contain a maximum of 64 secondary indexes." So, regardless of data length, even InnoDB is still stuck with 64 max (secondary) indexes.