# MYSQL : too many key parts specified max 16 parts allowed

Tags: mysql

The following query:

```
create index idx_test_17 on testable (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17);
```

Gives the error:

> too many key parts specified max 16 parts allowed

Is there any parameter to change to allow the above query to execute?

I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Most likely, you don't need such a massive index.  Please post the query and perhaps a workaround can be given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql error 1069 Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021586/mysql-error-1069-too-many-keys-specified-max-64-keys-allowed)

Comment: In my experience, if such a large composite key is needed,  it is time to look at the query design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

No, it is not configurable. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-limits.html says:

> - A maximum of 16 columns is permitted for multicolumn indexes.

It's a constant in the code:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_const.h#L40

```
#define MAX_REF_PARTS 16U    /* Max parts used as ref */
```

A given storage engine might reduce the maximum columns per index, but it will still be a fixed value. A storage engine cannot increase the maximum to a value greater than the constant shown above.

I've never seen a case where an index needed more than 16 columns. It's not clear in your question why you are trying to do this, but I recommend you reconsider if this seems like what you need. Either the table or your query needs to be redesigned, or else you must accept that you can't optimize the query in the way you are trying to do.