# How to create a schema with./configure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, key, schema, workbench

I am completely new to MySQL and the schema we need to use is a Copy of our production environment, which is on a different provider.

Basically from Oracle with a Tool we need to Copy a couple of DB tables to mySQL instance. The error we get is:

```
Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed.
```

This error should be fixed with  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021586/mysql-error-1069-too-many-keys-specified-max-64-keys-allowed)):

```
According to the mysql forums you must compile with:
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-charset=cp1251 --enable-thread-safe-client --with-max-indexes=256
```

The problem now is that we have no idea how to actually do this in mysql. We use Workbench 8.0C.
What we tried is to create a new schema and include the above code in the creation script. But to no avail.

Can somebody explain exactly how we can achieve this from the beginning as we are totally unfamiliar with Workbench and we cannot achieve the result looking through the forums.

EDIT: Nothing I try actually works and my tables are skipped when copying. I still get the same error of 64 keys.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekxcB.png)

First is the error, then it is the my.cfn file with the ./configure script, and third is the location of the Instance MySQL80 where the .cnf file is.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'll look to see which of the keys can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question! Creating a schema with./configure in mysql is a two-step process. First, you need to create a file called "my.cnf" in the same directory as your mysql executable. This file will contain the configuration settings for your schema. The second step is to actually create the schema using the "mysql" command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to be sure: mysql executable you mean the directory of the .exe right? C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
Do I need to refer to this file in some way when creating the schema?

Comment: Hi, can you look at the updated question? Seems like I cant make the .cnf file correctly and I still get the same 64-key error.